# How to make bitcoins from other cryptocurrencies?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins, altcoin-trade

I want to know how can I convert other cryptocurrencies like BlackCoin or LiteCoin to Bitcoin. There are many cryptocurrencies out there and the main difference between most of them and Bitcoin is popularity. At the moment, Bitcoin is way more commonly accepted as a payment option than the other cryptocurrencies, so they aren't really useful or flexible at all... So please tell me and explain how can I do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to convert them is by trading one for the other, or by going through a third currency.

Meaning:

- Find a person or exchange platform that trades exactly the currency pair you want e.g. LTC/BTC or BLK/BTC.
- Trade LTC -> USD -> BTC

Some exchanges trade a number of different altcoins, so they would lend themselves to do what you want. I have no experience trading anything but Bitcoin, but I've seen that for example HitBTC trades LTC/BTC, and BTER trades BLK/BTC.

I have used neither exchange and therefore cannot recommend them, just giving them as examples.

Comment: I thought about this way but I hoped there would be another one...Anyway,what does "altcoin" mean?

Comment: @VIPaul: [Altcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Altcoin) is the umbrella term for Cryptocurrencies forked from Bitcoin.

Comment: @VIPaul take a look at [shapeshift.io](http://shapeshift.io)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in New York or North Korea, you can use [ShapeShift](https://shapeshift.io/). If you are in New York or North Korea, you need to use a VPN to use the site. It doesn't even require you to make an account and you can easily swap between various cyrpto-currencies.

Comment: Interesting to see New York lumped with North Korea.

Answer (score 0):

there! You can easily user our platform ShapeShift.io, as another responder has mentioned. We support several dozen digital assets for exchange. If you would like to watch our demo video to see how to use our service, please check out our about page: https://info.shapeshift.io/about

We support both Blackcoin and Litecoin, we don't require you to create an account and it can take just a few minutes to process. Really easy, simple process!

Questions? Reach out to our customer support: https://shapeshift.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new